# Fetching tags from remote repository in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I have remote git repository, how can I fetch tags in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [git fetch man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---no-tags), by default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally.

So you should get most tags just executing VCS - Git - Fetch

However, if you refer to the `git fetch --tags` option, it is not possible in IntelliJ at the moment - vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159572